# Intellij idea plugin: Psi Classes

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am developing a plugin in Intellij idea. I am stuck at inserting a piece of code after a statement.

For eg:

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseflow(str,str,str);
```

I need to find the element `launchPurchaseflow` and add a piece of code after that statement.I used `PsiElement` and string matcher to get to the corresponding string.

Now my `PsiElement = mhelper.launchPurchaseFlow`.
If I use

```
psiClass.addAfter(newElement, PsiElement.getContext());
```

It is only trying to add after the closing paranthesis.So its pop out my new element as Incorrect Statement.

For eg:

Its adding at position

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseflow(str,str,str)//newElement;
```

But I need to add at

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseflow(str,str,str); // new Element.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give you a correct answer since you're not showing us how you are inserting the new text, but let's say you have a variable `PsiElement myElement` that contains the *expression* `mHelper.launchPurchaseflow(str,str,str)` (without the semicolon).
If you call `getParent()` on that element, you will likely have access to the *statement* representing the method call:

```
// Should represent "mHelper.launchPurchaseflow(str,str,str);" with the semicolon
PsiElement parent = myElement.getParent();
```

If you add your code after this node, it should produce a valid statement.

Alternatively, if `getParent()` does not return a `PsiStatement` and you want to be certain to have the full statement, you can do this:

```
PsiElement statement = PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(myElement, PsiStatement.class);
```